# Windows Firewall inbound rule - allow incoming connections from **named** computer

Tags: home-networking, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 10 laptop. My wife has an OS X MacbookPro. I set up the Mac with a static IP address on our home router, and I created an Inbound Rule in Windows Firewall to allow all inbound connection requests coming from the (fixed) internal IP address of the Mac machine.

So far so good, but this seems like overkill. Since the router has a name resolution table, it seems I should be able to allow connection requests from the Mac laptop by name (say "HerMacbookPro") rather than by IP address. The router should be free to assign IP addresses dynamically; when her Mac makes a request to access a database server on my Windows machine, that should still work. Is that possible in Windows Firewall?

I see where I can allow inbound connections from "Remote Computers". I see that I must change the Action from "Allow" to "Allow if the connection is secure." (Is this different from accepting inbound connection requests from an IP address? If it is different, why? Why is a secure connection required if the request comes from a named machine, but not if it comes from an IP address?) - anyway, I selected "Allow if the connection is secure" and then I went to the Remote Computers tab, checked the "Only allow connections from these computers" box under Authorized computers, and I clicked the Add... button.

This opens a new dialog box, with the title "Select Groups". WHAT GROUPS? Am I not supposed to select Remote Computers here? Then: "Select the object type:" - Groups or Built-in security principals. Huh? The object type I would like to select is a Remote Computer, I don't care which user is using the Remote Computer. (Same as allowing requests from this computer's IP address!) There is an "Object types..." button to select what type of objects to look for, but Computers is not among them.

OK, so I still enter the computer name in the "Enter the object names to select" box. The damn thing even has a web link "examples" that takes me to a Microsoft TechNet page with examples of object names. The web page is for Windows 8.1 through Windows Server 2012 R2 (highly professional on MS's part); anyway, it shows examples for "Object type = Computer" but there is no such option in the dialog box in the Firewall (contradicting the examples shown on the web page). I enter the computer name all the same and click Check Names; I get Name Not Found.

Thoughts? Did I miss some steps or is this not doable? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK - I posted the same on MS TechNet, and I learned that "Remote Computer" (allowing incoming connection requests by computer name) is only possible in a Windows domain, not in a private network. Bummer!